# Ubuntu screen problem

Tags: display

I have a problem with the ubuntu display. The ubuntu screen only covers middle portion of my laptop screen leaving to black bars on side. The screen almost looks like the screen which gets displayed when I connect the projector to my laptop. One of friend were pressing random keys and the screen got like this. What might be way to revert it, so that ubuntu screen cover the whole laptop screen?

I tried meddling with display option in the system settings but reached nowhere. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could be a change in resolution. Check display settings.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Try the following keys combination while on desktop:

Ctrl + Alt + **+** = Switch to next X resolution

Ctrl + Alt + **–** = Switch to previous X resolutionGo to this page:

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-shortcut-keys-in-ubuntu/

**Further note:** You can also search inside your machine for "Keyboard shortcuts" and read through them, spotting and fixing the one that created the trouble in the frist place.

*Hope it works, it worked for me when I accidentaly pressed a combination that messed with my display too.*

Comment: All the things he needs are there. I provided the link. Why would I copy-paste and make a huge post when the information can be diplayed by a simple click? I find it a little goofy to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I`ll take that in consideration from now on.

Comment: Done, I hope it's more explicit in the current form.

Comment: Nothing is working. Intially it got fixed when I restarted my computer. But now as soon as I enter my password my screen turns as if it is connected to projector.

Comment: Can you search for "Keyboard shortcuts", open it and check for anything related to "switch monitor", "displays", or something similar? Sorry for the question if you already did that.

Comment: I tried but haven't found anything like that.